# Application Context Null in different project and unable to access beans

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a project (project1) which has beans declared using @component and using application context I am able to access the beans. Now there is another project(spring boot project- project2) in which I am using this project1 as dependency.
In that I am trying to access beans of project1 using autowired annotation but it is throwing null pointer exception both for beans and Application context. How can I access application context of project1 which has access to those beans in my project so that I can use both autowired application context and access beans of project1 in project2
Any idea what is wrong and why autowiring not working.

Thanks

Comment: Are both projects packages configured to be scanned in project1? (@ComponentScan)

Comment: @ComponentScan is annotation is there on the classes of project1. Where else it needs to be declared? I need to use project1 beans in project2

Comment: Then in project2 the componentscan annotation must have both of project2 and project1 base packages. Like if project2 has the base package "a.b.c" and project1 has x.y.z project2 componentscan annotation must be @ComponentScan(basePackages={"a.b.c","x.y.z"})

Comment: those values are set but still it is unable to get the bean

Comment: I need to get the bean inside post construct method. It is working fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import configuration from project 1 into project 2. Something like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan({"abc.","com.abc"})
@Import({Project1Config.class})
public class Project2Configuration {
}
```